# Why "source" doesn't work in a script run as a Gnome's Desktop Entry?

Tags: bash, gnome, gnome-shell, intellij

I have a desktop entry pointing to `IntelliJ IDEA` IDE. I wanted to add `. ~/.bashrc` at the beginning of the `idea.sh` script that is being executed by Desktop Entry. The point of that is that IDEA wasn't picking up my modified `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env variable, that was defined there. So I added a very simple `. ~/.bashrc` at the beginning of `idea.sh`, to discover that the sourced code is not being run. Now some details.

In `~/.bashrc` I have this:

```
# Set GPG TTY
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)

unset SSH_AGENT_PID
if [ "${gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by:-0}" -ne $$ ]; then
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)"
fi

# Refresh gpg-agent tty in case user switches into an X session
gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye >/dev/null
```

I wanted this to run at the beginning of `idea.sh`, but `. ~/.bashrc` doesn't work, HOWEVER if I put this exact code directly in the `idea.sh`, in the same place, it will work just fine.

Sourcing also works if I run `idea.sh` directly in my terminal. It doesn't work only if I run it by using Desktop Entry. The desktop entry in question is `/home/luken/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition
Icon=/home/luken/Programy/idea-IU-182.4505.22/bin/idea.svg
Exec="/home/luken/Programy/idea-IU-182.4505.22/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Capable and Ergonomic IDE for JVM
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

So to sum this up:

## Running `idea.sh` in terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# IntelliJ IDEA startup script.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#

. ~/.bashrc
echo "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" > ~/auth.txt

# ...
```

Content of `auth.txt`: `/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh` **CORRECT**.

## Running `idea.sh`by using Desktop Entry shortcut:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# IntelliJ IDEA startup script.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#

. ~/.bashrc
echo "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" > ~/auth.txt

# ...
```

Content of `auth.txt`: `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh` **INCORRECT**.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# IntelliJ IDEA startup script.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#

# Set GPG TTY
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)

unset SSH_AGENT_PID
if [ "${gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by:-0}" -ne $$ ]; then
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)"
fi

# Refresh gpg-agent tty in case user switches into an X session
gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye >/dev/null

echo "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" > ~/auth.txt

# ...
```

Content of `auth.txt`: `/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh` **CORRECT**.

Anyone have any idea what is going on here or how to debug this?

Comment: [Exec doesn't execute more than one binary](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables). If you want to load environment variables, you need to specify them inline in the way of `VAR="variable" executable`.

Comment: But it's executing a single script. `source` is part of this script.

Comment: @steeldriver Bingo! I cannot belive I missed it (the early return). Post this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `~/.bashrc` file likely checks whether the shell that it is being sourced into is interactive or not, and in the latter case is returning before completing the instructions in question.

For example, the default `~/.bashrc` in Ubuntu systems has the following code near the top:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Also be aware that on some systems, `/bin/sh` may be a shell other than `bash` (for example, the `dash` shell) which may not support all of the features of your `~/.bashrc` file.